# How do I get answers involving conceptual discussion instead of solutions?

Tags: discussion

[Finding a general way to construct least degree polynomial having rational coefficient having irrational roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768168/finding-a-general-way-to-construct-least-degree-polynomial-having-rational-coeff)

[Removing superfluous functions from limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3767931/removing-superfluous-functions-from-limits)

[L'hopital rule fails with limits to infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3767136/lhopital-rule-fails-with-limits-to-infinity?noredirect=1#comment7752885_3767136)

Sometimes when I ask questions people are answering just the math problem and forgetting the particular issue that I raise which I am struggling with. Sure, solutions would help anyone who looks up the question but I think there is value for conceptual discussion in mathematics. How do I attract more of such answers to my questions?

Comment: The first question was asked a couple minutes ago, the second and the third seem identical.

Comment: pl check the edit in the q

Comment: Please write full sentences.  What is pl? Pleasure? what is q? quid? @DDD4C4U  You've asked 92 questions on main, yet you claim "Every time I ask questions people are answering just the math problem and forgetting the particular issue that I raise which I am struggling with."  Why do you keep coming back if you're unhappy here with answers you get??

Comment: it means "please check the edit in the question" , some of the question answers are good. Ok, actually I am gonna edit this question because 'all' questions are exaggeration

Comment: I appreciate the edit, @DDD4C4U

Comment: But the site moderates itself as QA site , and is not for having discussions

Comment: Does it? I thought all of stack exchange was for discussion from my experience with phys stack

Comment: @DDD4C4U, I get what you're trying to say. such answers take more time and effort so people usually avoid, and just name the particular theorem/identity. (which is something you can learn from external sources) I don't see a problem here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are looking for a general method or asking about something more conceptual then *say so clearly in the body of the question*.

Instead of stating a specific instance of your general problem and then rambling on a bit about it, as in your [first](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3768168/10513), state clearly what you are after:

> I managed to solve the following problem, but I am wondering if there is a general method which can be used to solve all such problems.

*Then* state your specific instance of the problem. If you have a solution to this instance then it is probably helpful to give it in the question. This potentially helps people answering the problem, but also makes it clear that you are after *more* than a solution to this instance.

A similar idea can be applied to your [third](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3767136/10513) question. First state what you are after:

> Something weird happened when I was playing around with L'Hôpital's rule, and I would like to understand it better. For example, consider the following problem:

*Then* state the problem etc. as you have done.

---

Also, as a side point, I got slightly confused and frustrated by the lack of full stops and capital letters in your questions, along with other things (0 not $0$, x not $x$, etc.). This can put off answerers. So if you do want more people to put in an effort to answer your questions then you should put in the effort to make them clear and smart and presentable.

Comment: I don't quite understand the last part. I am bad at English but I try to manage, if you have particular suggestions then say those.

Comment: @DDD4C4U If you want more people to answer your questions then you need to proofread them properly. My comments are *not* about language, but about writing in general: Finish your sentences with a full stop. Start your sentences with a capital. Use LaTeX for *all* mathematics (for example, in your first question you write p(x) but it should be $p(x)$, [x=a] should be $[x=a]$, or maybe $x=a$?). Your first question ends with a question mark on a line by itself (and there is a weird question mark in the line above...).

Comment: (In general, it would be excellent if everyone who was here wrote amazingly. But that is not realistic, so please don't think I am saying "you must write perfectly if you want to stay!". Rather, I am saying that your questions will be better received if you just take a bit more care when writing them.)

Comment: Oh you mean it like that. Hm, I will try to pay more attention to grammar and punctuations :)

Comment: I think "Finish...a capital" and [comments about question marks] *are* about language in that punctuation and capitalization expectations vary across languages (to say nothing about languages that don't have anything like capitalization). But of course writing all math in LaTeX is not about the language English, it is rather about the conventions of Math SE. Not necessarily you, but I think too often people judge posts on the English skills of the writer rather than editing the post or adapting. But I *do* agree with all of your suggestions as things that would improve a question's reception.